# how to convert PPER format to SPELL format for CoxPH model

Tags: survival-analysis, traminer, cox-regression

CoxPH Survival Analysis

I have a data set in PPER ( person period) format like :

Machine_id,Timestamp,Event,TDV1,TDV2,TDV3,TDV4
TDV1/2 are factors(brand , location) TDV3/4 are continous(temprature, humidity)

Need to convert to SPELL format like:
Machine_id,start.time,stop.time,event,TDV1,TDV2,TDV3,TDV4

I was able to convert from SPELL to PPER by using seqdef() & toPersonPeriod() in TraMineRextras

Help needed to do the reverse. Also how to treat continous variables while going from PPER to SPELL format?

Answer (score 0):

Person-period data is just a special case of spell data where the start and end times are identical. You get spell data by duplicating your `Timestamp` variable and renaming the first `start.time` and the second `stop.time`.

Possibly, you can aggregate your records using `list=c(Machine_id, event, TDV1, TDV2, TDV3, TDV4)` as `by` argument. Proceeding twice, once with `FUN="min"` and once with `FUN="max"`, you should be able to find the start and end times of the spells with unchanged values of `event` and the covariates.

```
I illustrate here with an example

## creating example data
p.df <- data.frame(scan(what=list(Id=0, timestamp=0, event="", work="", income=0)))
1 2000 S working 100
1 2001 S working 100
1 2002 M working 100
1 2003 M working 100
1 2004 M jobless 80
1 2005 M jobless 70
2 2000 S jobless 10
2 2001 S working 100
2 2002 S working 100

## leave previous line blank to end scan

p.df$start <- p.df$timestamp
p.df$end <- p.df$timestamp
p.df <- p.df[,-2]  ## deleting timestamp variable

bylist <- list(id = p.df$Id, event=p.df$event,
      work=p.df$work, income=p.df$income)
spell1 <- aggregate(p.df[,c("start","end")], by=bylist, FUN="min")
spell2 <- aggregate(p.df[,c("start","end")], by=bylist, FUN="max")

## reordering columns
spell <- spell1[,c(1,5,6,2,3,4)]
spell[,3] <- spell2[,6] ## taking end value from spell2
spell <- spell[order(spell$id,spell$start),] ## sorting rows
spell

##   id start  end event    work income
## 5  1  2000 2001     S working    100
## 4  1  2002 2003     M working    100
## 3  1  2004 2004     M jobless     80
## 2  1  2005 2005     M jobless     70
## 1  2  2000 2000     S jobless     10
## 6  2  2001 2002     S working    100
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: aggregate with min max giving same output, can you share with an example and code.